# How to change TextFormField initialValue dynamically?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm trying to use a value from a provider model to update the initialValue of a TextFormField, but the initialValue doesn't change.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:new_app/models/button_mode.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class EditWeightTextField extends StatelessWidget {


  const EditWeightTextField(
      {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return Consumer<ButtonMode>(builder: (context, buttonMode, child) {
        return TextFormField(
            initialValue: buttonMode.weight.toString(),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter weight';
              }
              return null;
            },
         
              );
    });
  }
}
```

if instead of a TextFormField I use a `Text(${buttonMode.weight}')` then the text is updated properly. What can I do to make it work with the TextFormField?

Comment: I would recommend you to use `TextEditingController(text: 'Initial value'); `, Let me know if you need a complete solution

Comment: I would appreciate a complete solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TextEditingController in this case.

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

Consumer<ButtonMode>(builder: (context, buttonMode, child) {

        if(buttonMode.weight != null && _controller.text != buttonMode.weight){ // or check for the null value of button mode.weight alone
             _controller.text = buttonMode.weight ?? '' ;
        }
        return TextFormField(
            controller : _controller,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter weight';
              }
              return null;
            },
         
              );
    });
```